# port 21 and 22 are open on a fresh install of mountain lion

Tags: ssh, security, firewall, port

I have Mountain Lion (fresh install as of today), I have also reset the router and it has no port forwarding or anything. There are no other devices connect to the router but just the mac. I did a port scan on my IP and found that port 21 and 22 were open.

The type of router that I have is a ubee ddw3612. The ISP that I am using is Charter and true or not I heard something about if a person knows your mac address they can spoof their and use my mac address to connect to the internet for free.

That is the only conclusion I can come to with these ports open and I have tried everything to be very sure its not the computer or the router. What do you think?

Comment: *What* is the only conclusion you can come to? You say "that", but there's no conclusion mentioned anywhere in the question.

Comment: I don't see a question. There is nothing wrong, SSH is very useful, and if you are not using it, you can close the ports.

Answer (score 1):

These are the default ports for SSH which is enabled by default on Mountain Lion. They should be open.

Comment: thing is though i went on the wifi with an ipad and had the mac turned off and i was still seeing port 21 and 22 open.

Comment: Seing them open where? Turning off your mac will not close ports on the router. In any case these ports are for ssh. If you don't use it, just close them.

Comment: but how do i see these ports open? I was on my wifi with only a ipad no other device was connected. I checked the connection list and it only showed the ipad. And i saw those ports open. The reason to me caring so much is that my bandwidth on certain hours of the day become slower than dialup.

Comment: How are you checking for open ports? If you are using an internet service, what you see is that the ports are open on your router.

Comment: the ports arent open on the router, port forwarding isnt enabled and its fully reset to default. i have checked in every section of the router webui and dont see anything that relates to ports. Is it possible for someone to conect to the internet using my mac address? (only with charter though since their service only works with the mac addr)?